# Error Installing ReactJS on Ubuntu20.04 (on Windows10 too)

Tags: reactjs

I am learning ReactJS, I've been following various tutorials but they all lead me to the same problem. Whenever I run `npm start`, I get

> webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
> throw err;
> ^

> Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)

and more... The last part of the error is:

> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

> npm ERR! errno 1

> npm ERR! reactApp@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot`

> npm ERR! Exit status 1

> npm ERR!

> npm ERR! Failed at the reactApp@1.0.0 start script.

> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

`Node --version`: v10.19.0
`npm --version`: 6.14.11
`webpack --version`: 4.30.0
`npm webpack`: 5.21.2

A better description is in the screenshot attached. I've tried other solutions but they havent been helpful. Please, I could really use some help. Thank you in advance.

The contents of the log file are:

(0) info it worked if it ends with ok
(1) verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
(2) info using npm@6.14.11
(3) info using node@v10.19.0
(4) verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
(5) info lifecycle reactApp@1.0.0~prestart: reactApp@1.0.0
(6) info lifecycle reactApp@1.0.0~start: reactApp@1.0.0
(7) verbose lifecycle reactApp@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
(8) verbose lifecycle reactApp@1.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/tdiah/Documents/NewIsh/reactApp/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
(9) verbose lifecycle reactApp@1.0.0~start: CWD: /home/tdiah/Documents/NewIsh/reactApp
(10) silly lifecycle reactApp@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot' ]
(11) silly lifecycle reactApp@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
(12) info lifecycle reactApp@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
(13) verbose stack Error: reactApp@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot`
(13) verbose stack Exit status 1
(13) verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
(13) verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
(13) verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
(13) verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
(13) verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
(13) verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
(14) verbose pkgid reactApp@1.0.0
(15) verbose cwd /home/tdiah/Documents/NewIsh/reactApp
(16) verbose Linux 5.8.0-41-generic
(17) verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
(18) verbose node v10.19.0
(19) verbose npm  v6.14.11
(20) error code ELIFECYCLE
(21) error errno 1
(22) error reactApp@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot`
(22) error Exit status 1
(23) error Failed at the reactApp@1.0.0 start script.
(23) error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
(24) verbose exit [ 1, true ]

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPOJb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue, then I just replaced this line `webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot` with `webpack serve --mode development --open --hot` in package.json